# Jquery toggle for multiple nested list items not working

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list with a jQuery prepended toggle button (.menu-expand). When clicked this toggles a class to open the sub menu.

The problem is the class is being added to all the submenus so they all open when the first toggle button is clicked.

I can't alter the HTML structure so need a solution in jQuery to toggle each submenu independently using the prepended toggle button. Can any one help please?

I've tried using .next() but I couldn't get this to work.

Here is the HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="has-dropdown">
    Item
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Sub Item 1</a>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">Sub Item 2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <a href="#">Sub Item 3</a>
                <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Sub Item 4</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Sub Item 5</a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
jQuery('.has-dropdown').prepend('<a class="menu-expand">+</a>');

$(".menu-expand").on("click", function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
    jQuery(this).closest('.has-dropdown').find('ul.dropdown').toggleClass('active');

})
```

CSS:

```
ul.dropdown{
  display:none;
}
ul.dropdown.active {
  display:block;
}
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8kwt6jqr/)

Comment: Side note, your HTML is invalid. Only a `<li>` can be a child of a `<ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salam, you can use children() function instead of find(),

```js
jQuery('.has-dropdown').prepend('<a class="menu-expand">+</a>');

$(".menu-expand").on("click", function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
jQuery(this).closest('.has-dropdown').children('ul.dropdown').toggleClass('active');

})
```